# Are refrigerator section pickles (Clausen) safe if left unrefrigerated?

Tags: food-safety, pickling, mold

I bought some Clausen Pickles, not knowing the jar said "always refrigerate'". I mean they were in the refrigerated section at Kroger. But They stayed up in my cabinet for about a week and a half, before I put them in the refrigerator. Then after about 2 days, to let them get good and cold, there was a film in the juice and some on the pickles. But it wiped right off of the pickles. But the film in still in the juice. Would you say they're okay to eat? I need some opinions. They still taste the same.. Maybe a little different.

Answer (score 2):

I called Heinz (Kraft), the makers of Clausen Pickles. They told me that they **can't recommend consuming their pickles labeled "always keep refrigerated" if the package has been unrefrigerated for as long as a week and a half**. Even if the jar is still sealed, they won't assure us that it is still safe to eat the pickles.

That seems like very much a CYA statement, but it is from the horse's mouth.

So, consider yourself warned that the pickles *may* not be safe.

The old adage **When in Doubt, Throw it Out** seems to apply here.